# How do I determine if a SQL record was changed by the system vs a user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table containing customer accounts:

| Id | AccountHolder | AccountNumber | AccountTotal | AccountStatus | LastUpdatedByUserId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6F439F45-04B1-486A-88F2-F8ACB29A4BA5 | MR D FLEMMING | 1012 | 2563.10 | 1 | 00B64F21-67FE-4F93-AE38-39D06934DC64 |
| FBF8E8D0-1CF3-4140-AE14-881F749C7A72 | MRS A SIMMONS | 3302 | 1020.60 | 4 | 3406711A-2C3E-42FE-ABB1-A2FFCB25B732 |
| CAB06298-5A15-41C4-94B0-086103D1D081 | MRS L JACOBS | 9655 | 5648.00 | 2 | 6E356113-8AEE-4348-AF39-3703E94936D1 |
| E516AADB-CDE7-4193-9588-F6C0BF03C3D3 | MR R SMITH | 7458 | 9863.25 | 4 | E742C2F6-4402-4395-A66F-9A2A9E87851D |
| E7E7AFAE-3D40-48E3-9D16-FA842144C652 | DR T WILKENS | 1458 | 5732.85 | 3 | F2791BF7-B8C4-4725-8F37-2801E38E51E2 |

The AccountStatus field is defined by the following Enum:

```
public enum AccountStatus
{
    New = 1,
    Finalized = 2,
    Amended = 3,
    Deleted = 4
}
```

The status is set as follows:

- New - Account created
- Finalized - Account submitted/sent to account holder
- Amended - Changes are being made to account/edited
- Deleted - Account deleted by user or by the system (see below***)
- When the User finalizes an Amended account, a new entry is created with status Finalized, and the Amended account is marked as Deleted***

We want to implement a clean up task identify and delete all the records that were marked as Deleted by the system.

How do I identify all the records that were marked as deleted by the system and not by the user?

Comment: Is there any flag for LastUpdatedByUserId to identify whether it's a system or user ?

Comment: Unless you store who made the delete you can't.

Comment: What does `the system` mean? All operations are executed using specific credentials. If each user connects with different credentials you can create an UPDATE trigger that stores the name or ID of the current user in a field, eg `SYSTEM_USER` and check whether that value matches the application's service account

Comment: You already have a column `LastUpdatedByUserId`. Can't you use that to determine if the last case was made by a non-user account?

Comment: Why dont' you just delete them immediately?

Comment: @Charlieface the table is getting quite large and deleting a record is much slower than updating a record. We also want to keep a record of the items deleted by users. Its the items deleted by the system that we don't need to keep.

Comment: There's no particular reason why that should be, maybe you need better indexing. Deleting a row rewrites the page it is stored on, but so does updating it, so it should be the same.

Comment: @Charlieface there are many reasons why delete is slower than an update. Such as having to check all foreign key constraints and having to keep track of changes in case the transaction fails and has to rollback. This is especially true in our case, as we are using Entity Framework where queries are executed in a transaction scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column named `MarkedDeletedBy` which for example will have a value of 1 or 0; 1 indicating system and 0 indicating user. Then just delete the rows which have 1 as the value of `MarkedDeletedBy`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your user ids are defined in another table and you don't have specific user Id for system.
Then, You may get records with status 4 and not in that user table.

Or if you have a specific user id for your system you may filter your data with status 4 and for that specific user.